# Ubuntu 12.10 No Wifi after updates

Tags: 12.10, wireless

My Wifi disappeared after 80 software updates package from Ubuntu. Im new to Ubuntu. Im using Acer Aspire 5742. The Wifi was there after the installation of Ubuntu but after I did the updates my Wifi no longer works.

Comment: what wifi card do you have? You can find out by typing the  command `lspci` into the command line and then pressing enter. In the output, look for a line with "Network controller" and include that in your post. Had a very similar problem with my "Broadcom Corporation BCM4313" today...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, however I was able to solve it.  I cannot exactly remember how, but try using the code `rfkill list all` in the terminal.  I remember using that code, but I do not remember if I used any follow-up codes.  Hopefully that works, but if not the results you get from that might be able to help other, more experienced, ubuntu users to help solve your problem.